# bash script command not found - command correctly implemented

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I wrote a bash script and i got these message:

/home/myname/documents/myscripts/run_tearingmode.sh: line 44: mpirun2: command not found:

Here the relevant part of the script

```
if [[ "$run_jobs" == "y" ]]
 then
 printf "The jobs run one after the other. Have fun with the analysis. \n "
 for ((i=1;i<=$number_subfolders;i++))
  do
  sub_folder=${main_folder}_$i
  cd
  cd gkw/run/${main_folder}/$sub_folder #change into certain subfold
  pwd
  mpirun2 -np 8 ./gkw_btppx-gnu-DP_3481.x  #run on all 8 frames #line 44 Here is the problem 
  cd
 done
fi
```

My problem is, that when i type in the line as just a command in the certain folder, the programm runs correctly. This shows to me that i implemented it correctly. With pwd i also know that i am in the right folder.
I didn't found out where i made the mistake. Do i need a certain bracket or equivalent things in a script for running a program?
I also deleted the blank in front of the command, but nothing changed.
What is wrong/missing?

EDIT: The problem was, that you can't run an alias from bashrc in such a script. 
So i added:

```
mpirun2='/Path/to/mpirun'
```

to my script and changed the command in the script to:

```
"$mpirun2" -np 8 ./gkw_btppx-gnu-DP_3481.x  #run on all 8 frames
```

This works. 
Thanks a lot. (I unfortunately can't write this answer myself as a starter :) )

Comment: Check the value of the `PATH` environment variable when your script is run (i.e. `echo $PATH`). Specifying the full path to `mpirun2` should help.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add a shebang on top of your script

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
```

and the **full path to your executable** (this command shows it `which mpirun2`) this should work.

Comment: I do have 

      #!/bin/bash
at the beginning of my script. 
Until i want to start the programm, my script runs well.
I also have named the mpirun2 as an alias in the bashcr

      alias mpirun2='/home/myname/mpich2/bin/mpirun'

.What is the acutal path of that folder?

Comment: Your alias is not available in your script. Instead of an alias, add this to your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (not `.bashrc`): `PATH="/home/myname/mpich2/bin/mpirun:$PATH"`.

Answer (score 1):

If mpirun2 is not on the user's PATH ('which -a' will return nothing). You must invoke it using full path to it:

```
/full/path/to/mpirun2 -np 8 ./gkw_btppx-gnu-DP_3481.x
```